Question about the proof of Serre finiteness theorem
I'm studying the Serre finiteness theorem:

Theorem The homotopy group $\pi_i\left(S^n\right)$ is finite for all $i$ except for $i=n$ and if $n$ is even for $i=2 n-1$, when it is finitely generated of rank 1 .

I'm studying this short proof from Miller's lectures page 241:

Proof. The case $n=1$ is special and simple, so suppose $n \geq 2$. Let
$$
S^n \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, n)
$$
represent a generator of $H^n\left(S^n\right)$. It induces an isomorphism in $\pi_n$ and in $H_n$.
When $n$ is odd, it induces an isomorphism in rational homology, and therefore in rational homotopy.
When $n$ is even, we should compute the cohomology of the fiber $F$. The class $\iota_n$ on the base survives to a generator of $H^n\left(S^n ; \mathbb{Q}\right)$, but $\iota_n^2$ must die. The only way to kill it is by a transgression from a class $\iota_{2 n-1} \in H^{2 n-1}(F)$ : $d_{2 n} \iota_{2 n-1}=\iota_n^2$. Then the Leibniz formula gives $d_{2 n}\left(\iota_n^k \iota_{2 n-1}\right)=$ $\iota_n^{k+2}$, leaving precisely the cohomology of $S^n$. So the fiber has the same rational cohomology as $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2 n-1)$. The generator $\iota_{2 n-1}$ gives a map $F \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, 2 n-1)$ that induces an isomorphism in rational homology, and hence in rational homotopy.

I've got two questions:

In the previous lecture they computed the rational cohomology ring of $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$. The thing that I don't understand is that in the case n odd they said that the map $S^n \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ induces isomorphism in rational homology. Why is that true? Is it possible to compute the homology from the cohomology ring? Why does the map $S^n \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ induces an isomorphism in rational homology?

In the case n even, I understand that $d_{2 n}\left(\iota_n^k \iota_{2 n-1}\right)=$ $\iota_n^{k+2}$, but I don't understand the conclusion. Why does $d_{2 n}\left(\iota_n^k \iota_{2 n-1}\right)=$ $\iota_n^{k+2}$ imply that the fiber has the same rational cohomology as $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2 n-1)$. And why does the generator $\iota_{2 n-1}$ give a map $F \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, 2 n-1)$ that induces an isomorphism in rational homology?



Rational cohomology is just the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear dual of rational homology (by universal coefficients), which is a conservative functor, meaning it reflects isomorphisms. So a map induces an isomorphism on rational homology iff it induces an isomorphism on rational cohomology.

@QiaochuYuan thank you for the answer. I don't think I understand what you wrote. What does it mean that it is the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear dual of rational homology? And why is it conservative? Can you give me some reference so that can I study all of this?

@marc There's two inputs here: The theory of dual spaces, in the sense of linear algebra, and the universal coefficient theorem. Look up the latter in any algebraic topology textbook, show that the $\operatorname{Tor}$-term appearing is trivial since you're working over a field, and deduce that the evaluation or Kronecker pairing is perfect. Then apply what you know from linear algebra about dualization/dual spaces. I moreover suggest spending some time with the UCT in general, because arguments like this are fundamental to what you're asking here and elsewhere and usually assumed understood.

@BenSteffan Thank you for the answer, I will follow your suggestions.

@BenSteffan do you have any suggestion for the second question? Why does  $d_{2 n}\left(\iota_n^k \iota_{2 n-1}\right)=\iota_n^{k+2}$ imply that the fiber has the same rational cohomology as $K(Z,2n−1)$

@marc If the question remains open I'll look at it this weekend.

@BenSteffan Thank you!

I'll answer the second question only since the first one has been resolved as its own question.
We write $H^*({{-}})$ and $H_*({{-}})$ for cohomology and homology, respectively, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.
For the statement about the cohomology of the fibre, let's visualize what the spectral sequence looks like: 
Here the shaded cells are all zero. It should be relatively clear why it has this form from Miller's description, but let's go over the important points again really quick. The group $E_2^{n, 0} \cong \mathbb{Q}$ accounts for the convergence to $H^n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and therefore survives to the $E_\infty$-page, by choice of map $S^n \to K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ and the edge homomorphism. Since all other cohomology groups of $S^n$ are zero, all the other groups and differentials must now be arranged in a way so that nothing else survives to the $E_\infty$-page. The next obvious group that we must kill is $E_2^{2n, 0} \cong \mathbb{Q}$; the only chance to do so is through the transgression $d_{2n}\colon E_{2n}^{0, 2n - 1} \to E_{2n}^{2n, 0}$ which must therefore be an isomorphism. But then we're almost done: The multiplicative structure tells us that all the other possible $d_{2n}$'s are isomorphisms as well, so we've accounted for all the groups. The last thing we need to make sure of is that $H^q(F) = 0$ for all $q > 2n - 1$, but this is clear since for the lowest such $q > 2n - 1$ that $H^q(F) \neq 0$ we see that the group $E_2^{0, q}$ would automatically survive to $E_\infty$ since nothing can kill it.
The statement about the generator is then a simple application of representability and the statement about duality of your first question: Since $H^{2n - 1}(F; \mathbb{Z}) \cong [F, K(\mathbb{Z}, 2n - 1)]$, it suffices to pick a lift $\varphi$ of $\iota_{2n - 1}$ to integral cohomology; by definition, $\varphi$ then induces an isomorphism $\varphi^*\colon H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}, 2n - 1)) \to H^*(F)$, so it also induces an isomorphism $\varphi_*\colon H_*(F) \to H_*(K(\mathbb{Z}, 2n - 1))$.
